# How to get output for for_each loop condition within terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a resource block with for_each loop condition and I wanted to output name and address_prefixes of the resource block.

**main.tf:**

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "snets" {
    for_each = var.subnets
    name = each.key
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
    address_prefixes = [each.value]
}
```

I have tried something like this, but it didn't worked.

**output.tf**

```
output "azurerm-subnet" {
    value = azurerm_subnet.snets.*.name
}
```

**Error:**

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on output.tf line 2, in output "azurerm-subnet":
│    2:     value = azurerm_subnet.snets.*.name
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can most easily be accomplished with a `list` constructor and a `for` expression. We iterate through the `map` of exported attributes for the `azurerm_subnet.snets` and return the `name` value on each iteration:

```
output "azurerm_subnets" {
  value = [ for subnet in azurerm_subnet.snets : subnet.name ]
}
```

and the output `azurerm_subnets` will be a `list(string)` where each element is the subnet name.